# C# (.NET), http web request (post method) with Auth. and Cookies

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, request

I'm trying to press one button in site opskins with C# app. When I press on it in browser, fiddler give me next

[image]

I don't have enough experience for that, so I think I add excess headers, make stupid mistakes, etc...

My code:

```
string username = textBox2.Text;
string password = textBox3.Text;
string userData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

/*Add Auth Header*/
string referer = "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_checkout";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(referer);

/*Cookie and spec. Headers*/
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "Cookie string from Fiddler here");
request.Headers.Add("X-OP-UserID", "2484329");
request.Headers.Add("X-CSRF", "2kXrd2qBf4eFxW1O6tM2ye3DELn4SJzDH");

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + userData);
string fData = "action=buy&hidden_bal=0&total=" + textBox1.Text + "&accept_tos=1&type=2";
byte[] eData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
request.ContentLength = eData.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
stream.Write(eData, 0, eData.Length);
}
```

When my app is running, fiddler give me

[image]

But still not working, what i must fix or add to my code?
Someone can tell me easier way to press one button in my site (only C#) ?

Comment: The net library doesn't support http1.1 which is chunk mode.  With chunk the client has to request next chunk and there is no way of issuing the new chunk using HttpWebRequest.  I would use http1.0 instead :             request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: Try using this HTTP 2.0 library for C# https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Fiddler, the url in your request constructor should be `"https://opskins.com/ajax/shop_buy_item.php";`

Try to use `CookieContainer` to stash your cookies and add each of your cookies you want to send in the request.

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(new URI("https://opskins.com"), new Cookie(key, value);
```

Also add this header: `request.Referer = referer`

If that still doesn't work, I'd recommend adding the rest of the headers from the first Fiddler request into your web request.

Comment: [Screen here](https://pp.vk.me/c837722/v837722394/202e3/y7J5tXyfOHU.jpg)  , 404:( how it's possible?

Comment: You're still missing some headers from your first Fiddler request ie `X-Requested-With`. To rule out these errors, make your request identical to the original Fiddler request.

You can add these headers using `request.Headers.Add(headerName, headerValue)`

If you still get 404, you might refresh your cookie value if it is set to expire.