# Posting to a form, can't get the address right

Tags: c#, html, http, post

I have intercepted an HTTP POST as follows

Header

```
Key Value
Request         POST /east-berkshire/local/quick_search HTTP/1.1
Accept          text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer         https://www.netmums.com/east-berkshire/local/index/childcare/nannies-au-pairs
Accept-Language en-GB
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host            www.netmums.com
Content-Length  107
DNT 1
Connection      Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie          AMCV_44326DF2572396FB7F000101%40AdobeOrg=817868104%7CMCMID%7C34574735755395522184062187835447062918%7CMCAAMLH-1486721296%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1486721296%7CNRX38WO0n5BH8Th-nqAG_A%7CMCOPTOUT-1486123696s%7CNONE; _ga=GA1.2.258060262.1486116497; _gat=1; _lp4_u=dZXxbBpqGf; __qca=P0-238174588-1486116496764; _tynt_crtg=; aam_uuid=34158303305859258534090346121149142657; __gads=ID=b3ba42a045f2be6a:T=1486116505:S=ALNI_MZHsVecqphdMO7SI-l4IEGrCyFpsg; AMCVS_44326DF2572396FB7F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; ABTastySession=LiwioHashMRASN%3Anull%5E%7C%5ELiwioUTMC%3A1; ABTasty=ABTastyUTMB%3A1%5E%7C%5ELiwioTracking%3A17020310101198682%5E%7C%5EsegmentationTracking%3A17020310101198682%5E%7C%5ELiwioUTMA%3A0.1.1486116611618.0.1486116611618.2; firstvisit=1; Cake=3qdc1afjmdvq0fg9kdunu2okn4; NetmumsLocation=east-berkshire; OX_plg=swf|sl|shk|pm
```

Body

> _method=POST&data%5BListing%5D%5Blisting_category_id%5D=2&data%5BListing%5D%5Blisting_subcategory_id%5D=211

I have written the following C# code to try simulate this

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.netmums.com/east-berkshire/local/quick_search") as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null) throw new HttpRequestException("Could not create web request");

        request.Method = "post";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var bs = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[Listing][listing_category_id]=2&[Listing][listing_subcategory_id]=211");
        using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);

        string result;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream == null) throw new HttpRequestException("No data returned");
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
```

However when I execute it, on the GetResponse() call I get the error

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986908/c-sharp-net-http-web-request-post-method-with-auth-and-cookies#comment71151869_41986908